# Can't load leaflet maps in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, leaflet

I've load the the style and the js in my function.php (you can see it in the last of each group)

```php
function recursos_ah6studio(){
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_theme_file_uri('/css/bootstrap.min.css'));
    wp_enqueue_style('slick', get_theme_file_uri('/slick/slick.css'));
    wp_enqueue_style('slick-theme', get_theme_file_uri('/slick/slick-theme.css'));
    wp_enqueue_style('magnific-popup', get_theme_file_uri('/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css'));
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', get_theme_file_uri('/fontawesome-5.5/css/all.min.css'));
    wp_enqueue_style('estilo_ah6studio', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_enqueue_style('leaflet_style', 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.css'); //here!

    wp_enqueue_script('chartjs', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js', NULL, '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('chartdatalabel', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js', NULL, '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_theme_file_uri('/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js'), NULL, '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('popper', get_theme_file_uri('/js/popper.min.js'), NULL, '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('boostrap', get_theme_file_uri('/js/bootstrap.min.js'), NULL, '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('slickJS', get_theme_file_uri('/slick/slick.min.js'), NULL, '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('magnific-popup', get_theme_file_uri('/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js'), NULL, '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('easingJS', get_theme_file_uri('/js/easing.min.js'), NULL, '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('singlePageJS', get_theme_file_uri('/js/jquery.singlePageNav.min.js'), NULL, '1.0', true); 
    wp_enqueue_script('tool-tip', get_theme_file_uri('/js/tooltip.js'), NULL, '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('leaflet_js','https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.js', NULL, '1.0', true); // and here

} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'recursos_ah6studio');
```

And put the code in my index.php I've even put some js that the official [quick start](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) of Leaflet tells you to start with

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
</script>
```

But it does not load the map. Am I doing something wrong?

My footer.php looks like this (someone ask for it):

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="tm-gallery-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 footer_text"><p>Copyright © 2021  |  Todos los derechos reservados | By DALF</p></div>
        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 social_icon">
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ah6studio">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/images/logo_fb.svg')?>" alt="facebook logo"></a>
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCgPsU_qjhhbCFNETiT7OCWg">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/images/logo_yt.svg')?>" alt="youtube logo"></a>
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ah6studio/">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/images/logo_ig.svg')?>" alt="instagram logo"></a>
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/77211866/">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/images/logo_Lin.svg')?>" alt="linkedin logo"></a>


        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>

 </body>

 
 </html>
```

Comment: What does your theme's footer.php look like?

Comment: I'll edit my post so you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress, you don't add any code to index.php. The comment at the top of the page starts with `"This file doesn't do anything..."`

To make modifications, you add code to the theme's `functions.php` or any one of the template files. For illustration I'll use the `footer.php` template file that you have provided. I've not tested the code, but this should display the map in the Footer of the page:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <div id="map"></div>
            <script>
                var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
            </script>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="tm-gallery-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 footer_text"><p>Copyright © 2021  |  Todos los derechos reservados | By DALF</p></div>
        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 social_icon">
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ah6studio">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/images/logo_fb.svg')?>" alt="facebook logo"></a>
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCgPsU_qjhhbCFNETiT7OCWg">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/images/logo_yt.svg')?>" alt="youtube logo"></a>
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ah6studio/">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/images/logo_ig.svg')?>" alt="instagram logo"></a>
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/77211866/">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/images/logo_Lin.svg')?>" alt="linkedin logo"></a>


        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>

 </body>

 
 </html>
```